# Windows cannot find taskmgr.exe

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-manager

Couple of days ago a program named similar to `windows 10 update assistant`, was downloaded auto to my windows 10 system. Stating,

> support for the version of windows 10 I am using will be running out
>   soon and I have to update my system to the latest version of windows
>   10

I was previously using,

> Windows 10 pro Edition, (probably Version 1607 - Anniversary Update)

It took the program more than a day to upgrade to the latest version. Ever since I upgraded I am unable to:

- access task manager
- access regedit
- access gpedit.msc
- access services
- Access restore point setting
- Access quick Assist
- Access remote assistant
- Access advanced system settings (I wanted to check environment variables)
- Open Command Prompt as administrator
- Access any major feature

While accessing all of the above features an error message similar to the following one appears, with the path of the .exe or .msc being accessed.

> Windows cannot find 'C:\Windows\system32\taskmgr.exe', make sure you
>   typed the name correctly and then try again

I explored the directory using windows explorer and tried opening the file directly but again the same error appears on the screen.

[image: [error message]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJlPG.png)

I tried to,

- Revert back to the previous version via

> settings app > update & security > recovery > go back to the previous
>   version of windows 10,

but clicking the `get started` button does nothing.

- Reset windows via

> settings app > update & security > recovery > reset this pc,

again clicking the `get started` button does nothing.

I believe its a small subset of features I am unable to access, since I haven't tried accessing everything.

I haven't hated windows 10 this much in all of this time, its been so annoying.

- First some subset of my custom settings for mouse etc. were reverted back to the defaults,
- all the programs pinned to my start menu(which were like a lot) were reverted back to the windows default.
- Now some of the pinned program icons are not appearing

How the hell I can get out of this nightmare,

Comment: Probably better to just download the current version and install afresh.

Comment: Press Ctrl+Shift+Esc from keyboard. Or run this command in command prompt: `where taskmgr.exe`. What did you see?

Comment: @Biswapriyo `C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe`, as I mentioned I explored the file and opening it manually still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Press Control + Alt + Delete
- Click Sign out
- At the Sign In screen, hold down the shift key while clicking the Power button on the screen
- Continue to hold down the shift key while clicking Restart from the pop up list
- Continue to hold down the shift key until Advanced Recovery Options menu appears
- Click Troubleshoot
- Click Advanced options
- Click Go back to the previous version of Windows

It would take 20-25 minutes to revert back to your previous version of windows.